# Error: /..integrator.vhd(47): near "process": (vcom-1576) expecting IF VHDL

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, asic

I'm trying to add two registers storing signed bits one of 3-bit[`FRQ(2 downto 0)`] and other is 7-bit[`PHS(6 downto 0)`]...and has to store the addition of these two registers in 7-bit register [`PHS(6 downto 0)`]. Thanks in advance for your helpful gesture.

the error I get is..>>>
*Error: /..integrator.vhd(47): near "process": (vcom-1576) expecting IF VHDL*

here is my code:

```
    library IEEE;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    --use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


    entity integ is
        port (
            SMP_CLK : in std_logic;
            RESET : in std_logic;
            PHS : out signed (6 downto 0);
            FRQ : in signed (2 downto 0)
              );
    end integ;

    architecture behaviour of integ is

    signal sig_FRQ   : signed(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal ext_FRQ   : signed(6 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal sig_PHS   : signed(6 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal temp_PHS   : signed(6 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    begin 

    sig_FRQ <=FRQ;
    temp_PHS <= sig_PHS;
    --PHS <=signal_PHS;
    process (SMP_CLK, RESET)
    begin

    if sig_FRQ(2)='1' then
        ext_FRQ(6 downto 3) <= b"0000";
    else 
        ext_FRQ(6 downto 3) <= b"1111";
    --end if;

    if RESET='1' then
       sig_PHS <= b"0000000";


    elsif (rising_edge(SMP_CLK) ) then
    --  temp_PHS <= sig_PHS;
           sig_PHS <= signed(ext_FRQ) + signed(temp_PHS);



end process;


sig_PHS => PHS;

end behaviour;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some mess with `if-elsif-else` statement. After the line with `ext_FRQ(6 downto 3) <= b"1111";` you have commented `--end if;` if you want to continue `if-elsif-else` statement next condition should start with `elsif` word rather than simple `if` as in your code.

And you need to close the `if-elsif-else` construction in the end.

As well as you need to add to sensitivity list `sig_FRQ` signal because you use it in comparison, if you don't add it to sensitivity list the following construction

```
if sig_FRQ(2)='1' then
    ext_FRQ(6 downto 3) <= b"0000";
else 
    ext_FRQ(6 downto 3) <= b"1111";
end if;
```

will work wrong.

In your case I suppose right version of the `if-elsif-else` constructions looks like:

```
process (sig_FRQ)
begin
    if sig_FRQ(2)='1' then
        ext_FRQ(6 downto 3) <= b"0000";
    else 
        ext_FRQ(6 downto 3) <= b"1111";
    end if;
end process;

process (SMP_CLK, RESET)
    if RESET='1' then
        sig_PHS <= b"0000000";
    elsif (rising_edge(SMP_CLK)) then
        --temp_PHS <= sig_PHS;
        sig_PHS <= ext_FRQ + temp_PHS;
    end if;
end process;
```

In the end, if you would like to assign result to output, you need to use another operator

`PHS <= sig_PHS;`.

Comment: I have to modify output port assignment but your suggestion was a lot helpful. Thanks a lot. Code is running now, although it need some rectification for proper addition. Since, after simulating it, I didn't got result as I expected. Anyhow, Thanks Again.!!

Comment: Got it working as expected.!! Anyhow, I am implementing a FSM for data communication, to be used in modulation schemes using digital design.

Comment: Ok, I was glad to help you anyway

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to put both assignments in one process. `ext_FRQ`=combinatorial and `sig_PHS`=clocked... Also, `ext_FRQ` and `temp_PHS` are already signed.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius ok, I fixed my answer, thanks for your advice

Comment: In case of  `RESET='1'` how should I assign all my signals to zero ?? Should I considered all signals used either in combinational or sequential logic or should I focus on sequential only?

Comment: @Gaurav Singh add `RESET` to each sensitivity list of the process when you want to use it. In this case you will get asynchronous reset